# Cant open github.com on safari nor access it in terminal in macos monterey 12

Tags: macos, github, macos-monterey

I am brand new to Mac and wondering what i cant access github.com from safari or from terminal with git clone. MyOS is 12.0.1 Monterey.

In Safari, it says "safari cant establish a secure connection with github.com" while terminal says unable to access github.com. No alternate certificate found.

What is the fix?

Comment: Is your time on your new Mac correctly set and synced to a timeserver?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke it is set to automatic and showing correct date time of my city.

Comment: Do other secure sites work (like this one)?  Does the behaviour change in Chrome?  Both browsers should have a way to inspect the cert (I'm more familiar w/ how to do it in Chrome than Safari).  If you can do that, you should be able to see WHY it's getting rejecting.  An "expired" cert is a good suggestion, that's why your date is important.  But, if you can see the cert, you can copy it and install it, and then tell the browser to trust it (in Chrome, anyway). Are you running this at work?  They might have a proxy in place, you might need IT to help add github.com to an allow-list.

Comment: @jimtut thanks for the input. I dont have chrome yet but I am more important in the terminal side of things more than the browser. I cant git clone, or ping github.com in terminal. I will try Chrome but still i am hoping to get around the terminal.

Comment: Is it a work Mac? Are you going thru some company firewall or proxy that could be blocking GH?

Comment: @jimtut no, I am at home network and my linux machine connects well. The MAC ON connects to all websites except github.

Comment: Use your Linux box to get the IP of GH, then try using that on the Mac, instead of the text GitHub.com. Also, try pinging the IP on the Mac. If that works, you have a DNS problem. If not, the IP is somehow blocked, but only on the Mac, which I cant explain if the Linux box is using the same router and the same connection type (Wi-Fi or Ethernet). I hope it’s a DNS problem!

Comment: @jimtut thanks. I did ping on the mac with the ip i got from linux. Opening it in browser with ip gives me certificate problem. at least that's something! i appreciate it